# What should we do about servo questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

As far as I understand it, the answers to questions related to [hobby (RC) servos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism#RC_servos) are likely to be very different to similar looking questions related to [industrial servomotors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism#Servomotor).

At the moment we have a single [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tag with covers all types of servo motors, so there are a mix of questions under this tag. I commented on several occasions, asking for clarification about the kind of servo, most recently [What are the signs that a servo might be broken?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1301/37)

I wonder if we might be better off with a [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) tag and an [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) tag (with a [hobbyservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobbyservo) tag synonym). We would retain the [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tag to remind people select the appropriate tag and to cover all servos which aren't either a [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) or an [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo).

Any thoughts, opinions or suggestions for this idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's do it....

Comment: I've retagged what I can, so hopefully this should reduce confusion in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Given that (at the time of this answer) we have only 23 questions tagged as [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) I'm not sure there is any need to segment?

Having said that, the two types you highlight are different enough to (probably) justify separate tags.  And if we are going to do it, then now is the time - before we have too many to re-tag easily...

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I agree with your second point, which is why I decided to bring it up now - while the problem is manageable. On your first point, I think we need to plan for the future, assuming that eventually we will be a roaring success. *8')