# 4 years later on the servo vs hobby servo tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

4 years after the [last discussion](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/what-should-we-do-about-servo-questions) I can find on this topic it looks like after around 2014 the [hobbyservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobbyservo) tag fell out of use and the [servo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servo) tag has become a catch all, as it seems that the majority of questions have not been about industrial servos, I propose that we simple make hobby servo a synonym of servo, and in questions asking about industrial servos posters call that out explicity.

We might also change to using an [industrialservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrialservo) tag for those requiring it because the large majority of beginners posting have no idea that what hey are using should be called a "hobby servo" as opposed to just a servo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) info page: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/servos/info

> Most [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) questions should fall into the subcategories of either industrial [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) or [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) (with the synonym [hobbyservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobbyservo)). Only questions which do not fall into these two sub-categories should use this tag.

To summarise this taxonomy of tags:

- 57 [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) questions, last in January 2017
- 42 [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) questions, last in October 2016
- 59 [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) questions, 5 asked so far this month

Part of the point of the [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tag is to help identify questions which haven't been correctly tagged as either either [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) or [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor).

The idea was that if you see a question tagged with [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos), anyone could suggest an edit to the question to re-tag it with [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) or [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) as required. If it wasn't clear from the question whether it was referring to an [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) or a [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor), then this could be clarified and then properly tagged.

There was a time when I would go through [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tagged questions myself doing this, but then the community started doing it, and I just had to approve the suggested edits.

Although it looks like a clean up may be required, I think the basic principle still stands and our current taxonomy is the correct solution top the problem of [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) questions being consistently being mis-tagged.

### 2020 Update

After making [hobbyservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobbyservo) and [digitalservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digitalservo) into synonyms of [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) and making [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) into a synonym of [otherservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otherservo) the problem seems to have reduced substantially:

- 70 [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) questions, up to Nov 29 '19
- 102 [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) questions, up to Dec 28 '19
- 33 [otherservos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otherservos) questions, up to Jun 9 '16

There are still questions in [otherservos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otherservos) which would be better off tagged with either [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo), [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) or both, and there are still questions tagged as one which should be more accurately tagged as the other, so feel free to edit these tags (or suggest an edit) when you find them.

Comment: Ahh I see I misunderstood, making the rookie mistake of only reading the top tag text and not the wiki text. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, feel free to suggest edits which re-tag [tag:servos] as either [tag:rcservo]or [tag:servmotors] as appropriate. I started to do it yesterday, but ran out of time, and sharing the load would be good.